# QGIS read only Project?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

I'm creating a project, but I don't want others to have permission to modify the project. So i want to create a read-only project in QGIS3.16.14, is it possible?

Comment: You can turn each layer of the project to read-only, and for the project file itself, I think you have to play with file rights on your system.

Comment: (Project Properties - Data sources)